# The Floating Effect - Issues with my code

Tags: html, css

I couldn't make the divs "float" when hovering. Everything moves with It. I tried to create a separate div just for the boxes I wanted to see floating, but It didn't fix It, so I ended up removing It. What's wrong with my code? I added the box-shadow effect but without the boxes moving up a little bit It looks kinda bland.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Valor Pago -->
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="row">
            <p>Valor Pago:</p>
            <!-- Texto -->
            <input type="text" size="35">
            <!-- Botão -->
            <div class="botao">
                <button size="20" onclick="valor1()" id="botao">Definir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Custo do Produto -->
    <div class="flex-container" id="custo">
        <div class="row">
            <p>Custo do Produto:</p>
            <input type="text" size="50">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Troco -->
    <div class="flex-container" id="troco">
        <div class="row">
            <p>Troco:</p>
            <input type="text" size="50">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Corpo */
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif;
}

/* Primeiro container (determinando também algumas características dos outros) */
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(49, 117, 218), rgb(0, 0, 107));
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}

/* Caixas que contém o texto (dentro dos containers): Valor Pago, Custo do Produto e Troco */
.flex-container > div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 24px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 22px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

/* Hover das caixas dentro dos containers */
.flex-container > div:hover {
    background-color: #cac9c9;
    transition: ease-out 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Configuração de posição e cor do container "Custo" */
#custo {
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgb(216, 0, 0), #570000);
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Configuração de posição e cor do container "Troco" */
#troco {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(17, 212, 82), rgb(0, 77, 0));
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

/*Configuração do div dos botões*/
.botao {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Configuração dos botões dentro dos divs */
#botao {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

/* Hover dos botões */
#botao:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
    transition: ease-out 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: When you say, "float" do you mean the style "float", that could be left or right?  If it is you always have to consider that the element that you set to float will float within its parent div.

Comment: Lusks — your rows are moving because your .flex-container > div:hover selector changes the top margin from 24px to 20px. Eliminate that change and your rows won’t move. Then you can play with the shadow to get the float effect you’re looking for (kind of like [Material Design](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button#interactive-demo)).

Comment: @mike_thecode Actually I want the boxes to look like they are floating when I'm hovering. It's not about the ''float'' property.

Comment: @RichDeBourke I wanted the boxes to move up, that's why I tried to add the margin-top. I don't want just the box-shadow. The problem Is, I can't figure out a way to make those boxes go up without moving the rest too. It actually works on the box on the green background, but not on the blue and red ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Adjusting the top and bottom margin for the transition keeps the rest of the page rock stead on Firefox, but on Chrome and Edge, things do move [maybe a bug, not clear](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/64530794?hl=en).

One solution would be to add some JavaScript to set the row heights (and adjust the height anytime there's a resize event), the way footers used to be stuck to the bottom, before flex using a [sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#comment-1601988) concept.

To have the boxes move up 4px while keeping the row heights stable, add the same amount (4px) to the bottom margin. The margins for your hover style would be:

```
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 28px;
```

Here's the full code with my change (with no movement of the rows):

```js
var produceRows = document.getElementsByClassName("product-row");

function setProductRowHeight() {
    var i;
    var rowHeight;

for (var i = 0; i < produceRows.length; i++) {
    produceRows[i].style.height = "auto";
    rowHeight = produceRows[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    produceRows[i].style.height = rowHeight + "px";
}
}

window.addEventListener('resize', setProductRowHeight);

setProductRowHeight();
```

```css
/* Corpo */
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif;
}

/* Primeiro container (determinando também algumas características dos outros) */
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(49, 117, 218), rgb(0, 0, 107));
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}

/* Caixas que contém o texto (dentro dos containers): Valor Pago, Custo do Produto e Troco */
.flex-container>div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 24px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 22px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

/* Hover das caixas dentro dos containers */
.flex-container>div:hover {
    background-color: #cac9c9;
    transition: ease-out 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}

/* Configuração de posição e cor do container "Custo" */
#custo {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(216, 0, 0), #570000);
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Configuração de posição e cor do container "Troco" */
#troco {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(17, 212, 82), rgb(0, 77, 0));
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

/*Configuração do div dos botões*/
.botao {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Configuração dos botões dentro dos divs */
#botao {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

/* Hover dos botões */
#botao:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
    transition: ease-out 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!-- Valor Pago -->
<div class="flex-container product-row">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Valor Pago:</p>
        <!-- Texto -->
        <input type="text" size="35">
        <!-- Botão -->
        <div class="botao">
            <button size="20" onclick="valor1()" id="botao">Definir</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Custo do Produto -->
<div class="flex-container product-row" id="custo">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Custo do Produto:</p>
        <input type="text" size="50">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Troco -->
<div class="flex-container product-row" id="troco">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Troco:</p>
        <input type="text" size="50">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The unwanted movements still happen a little bit. I'll try to use this as a way to find the best solution. Thank you!

Comment: I added the full code I used for testing which was a copy of the code you originally posted. If you run the code snippet, there's no movement.

Comment: There's still movement In the full screen version of It, but now I'm gonna put them together In the same row, to avoid the headache. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My bad - I had only viewed the code in Firefox (which is rock steady). When I looked at it in Chrome and Edge, I could see the movement. One solution (which I've added to my answer) would be to set the row height using JavaScript (and adjusting if there's any resize).